# only load images that are on screen in div with css overflow

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with 1000 images in it with overflow:auto set.  It is only 100 pixels high and about 80000 pixels wide.  This works fine but I would rather only load images that are actually on screen, so as the user scrolls right or left the images get loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@slee , there are various solutions for this.

you can use the jcarausal plugins for this type of things

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel

In my project i show 4 images and i load only those images, When the user clicks next or previous , i get the next four images and swap the src and ids,

This will definetly give better performance as every image is a http request...

reducing httprequests improve the performance

Comment: problem is I am using some jQuery drag and drop actions for connected lists.  I could have 1800 items in the jCarousel which seems to be a problem

Comment: 1800 , it will be definetly a performance issue. what about infinite load option , when you do horizontal drag you can load the images.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [lazy loader](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin? If you could find a more recent fork since the author claims it doesn't work with "modern" browsers, that would be best. Last I tested ( earlier this year ) it worked fine in everything but IE6. I suspect the author maybe referring to IE8/IE9.